Issue with VPC Service Controls
I want to create a boundary for the project using VPC Service Controls and allow connections only from specific IP addresses. Below is the VPC Service Controls configuration

Perimeter Title: test

Perimeter Type: Regular

Resources to protect: secure-*****（Project Name）

Restricted Services: All API Services

VPC Accessible Services: All services allowed

Access Levels: No access levels

Ingress policy:

  Ingress Rule 1

    From:

      Identities:ANY_IDENTITY

      Source > Access levels = vpn_ips

    To:

      Projects = All projects

      Services = All services

Egress policy: No egress policy

vpn_ips specifies the IP address with a subnet mask of 32. However, I am unable to access the secure-***** project. I am sure the IP address is being sent from the configured source.
I confirmed that setting Source > Access levels = vpn_ips to Source > All sources allowed enables access.
Additionally, I confirmed that the issue  was resolved, but even after reconfiguring, access was still not possible. Could there be something wrong with the configuration?
Below are the configuration details for Access Context Manager and a capture of the Audit Log. It appears that the IP addresses have been correctly configured.
Access Context Manager:
enter image description here
Audit Log:
enter image description here
I tried setting the Access Level for VPC Service Controls' Ingress to Geographic locations, but I was still unable to access it. It seems that this issue is occurring between VPC Service Controls and Access Context Manager.
